# PHP: random position functioning without overlapping

Tags: php

I have an block say 1000x600, and with in this block i have to randomly fill it with a blocks of 20x20 so giving me 1500 in total.

But as i place these within a random x,y position i want to ensure that i am not over writing an already allocated block. So my question and probably is there a better way to describe what i have done / doing in order to perform this task.

CODE:

```
    $Ypos = 0;
    $Xpos = 0;
    $posStore = [];
    $box_size =20;
    //-- this will be set by another mehtod and will be a rand ome nuber between 5 and 1500 
    //-- but set to the mx for now.
    $number_of_blocks = rand(5, 1500);

    //-- loop through the total number of blocks set
    for ($i=1; $i <=$number_of_blocks; $i++) { 
        //-- set the x,y position for th eblock
        self::SetPosition();

        //-- add the block code here
        //.........
    }


    //-- Set th ex,y position of the block 
    private function SetPosition(){
        //-- get the positions
        $this->Ypos = self::randYPos();
        $this->Xpos = self::randXPos();
        //-- check that we do not already have that position within the array else re-run this function
        if(in_array([$this->Ypos,$this->Xpos], $this->posStore)) {self::SetPosition();}
        //-- if ok then lets add this position to the array
        array_push($this->posStore,[$this->Ypos,$this->Xpos]);
        //-- return true
        return true;
    }


    //-- set the ypos
    private function randYPos(){
        $yPos = rand(0 , self::IMAGE_WIDTH);
        //-- as the boxes need to be positioned relative to their size (20) / incremented by their size so no
        //-- overlapping is occured  
        return ($yPos % $this->box_size == 0) ? $yPos :self::randYPos();
    }
    //-- set the xpos
    private function randXPos(){
        $xPos = rand(0 , self::IMAGE_HEIGHT);
        //-- see ypos explaination
        return ($xPos % $this->box_size == 0) ? $xPos :self::randXPos();
    }
```

Basically what i am doing is getting a random x,y pos that is incremented by the box size so it prevents overlapping.

I then pass the two values back and check that the position set has not already been allocated, by checking a positioning array ($posStore), if not then add that new position array to the positioning array ($posStore).

But this does not seem to work as if i like above set the total to max i still have spaces within my main 1000x600 block and it seems there are some instances of positions being overwritten etc

Is there a better way to write this (no-doubt) of am i missing something.

UPDATE

Although the shuffle answer(s) did not solve the whole issue it was a good factor in helping me resolving it.

As i might not completely fill my array(s) even shuffling would still display a linear effect, so what i did was to  fill in my array from 0,0 to the overall total.

I then used the php shuffle to shuffle :-)

Then taking the required total asked for i simple did a for loop and as they array totals where shuffled it gave em a mixed bag of results.

thanks for help

Comment: What are you dealing with `DOM` or some image that you create with php on server side?

Comment: looks like homework to me.  Why randomize it anyway? think logically its like laying paving slabs you start in the top left you know your fixed bounding box size, you know your slab size, you can calculate the x and y positions for the top left of every slab.

Comment: Yeah! not really i have a call in the function that has to params linear or random, the linear one works fine no probs its the random one

Comment: do it linear store in an linked list or an array then just shuffle  them for generation order ? no overlaps then and since you're not accounting for partial slabs there is only one way to organise them just your method of laying order is random

Comment: Ah! so did as in my linear way (add them to an array) all first then shuffle that then do the visual adding? i am seeign it now should have thought of this first would probably reduce calls...?

Comment: well you just have a pregeneration phase if you like which creates your primary array. then juse a single call to the built in shuffle function, then a simple loop through array to display will give you your "apparent" random laying of the slabs which will visually appear different every time the page is ran.  you don't need to go back and check for overlaps at all.  Not unless you're allowing for partial slabs ie: 1/2 full full full 1/2 etc instead your always going to be full full full full per row and column

Comment: Wait: if doing it linear and the total sent to the loop $number_of_blocks does not match the overall total of the blocks, so i have 300 blocks sent through this would only randmise the first section so thus the bottom half would look blank still?

Comment: you know total height and width and block height and width you can calculate the top left position of each block thats all you need store each coord par is an array within an array then just shuffle the master array not the sub arrays read out and draw your image starting from the coords retrieved. for whatever you earlier specified the block as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the sequential space ([x, y] pairs in an array) and then [shuffle](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) it.

Comment: thank for the mention of the shuffle, it did not solve my issue totally but was a part of the ending and used in conjunction to solve my issue, sop thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can lay out them in rows and columns, this will allow you to fit the maximum amount of boxes easily.

Then just shuffle them. Go through all of them, one by one, and switch position with a randomly chosen block. Pseudocode:

```
for i from n − 1 downto 1 do
       j ← random integer with 0 ≤ j ≤ i
       exchange a[j] and a[i]
```

Source [Fisher-Yates Shuffle, Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)